# Многополосный эквалайзер в linux

Tags: linux, аудио, alsa, pulseaudio

Есть наушники и нужно произвести тонкую настройку эквалайзером, обычный pusle эквалайзер не подойдет.
В windows есть Equalizer APO нужно что-то подобное, искал в сети нашел только вот [это](https://lsp-plug.in/?page=home), там на скринах у них есть 32 полосный эквалайзер, и как я понял это просто плагин без ui интерфейса, не понятно как им пользоваться, как запустить.

Мне нужен просто расширенный эквалайзер с графическим интерфейсом, без другой работы со звуком типа midi и т.п
Может кто сталкивался уже с подобным?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в сети, https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects 30 полосной эквалайзер и ещё много других фичей.
Так же классный проект с данными измерений многих ушей https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects